# simply outputting @Model value in img src or a href

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

New to Razor and I am missing somethign simple here:

```
    @foreach (var p in @Model)
        {
<a href="/category/@Html.Display("CategoryID")" >
         <img src="http://images.mydomain.com/productimages/@ViewData["ManufacturerID"]/category-@Html.Display("CategoryID")_lg.jpg?width=200&height=130" width="200" height="130" class="myImg" alt="" />      
</a>  
    }
```

I simply want to out put the CategoryID here, the link above does not output a value for CategoryID. What am I doing wrong here?

My model is populated since I can drop this in the loop and it displays: `@p.CategoryName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
@foreach (var p in @Model)
{
  <a href="/category/@p.CategoryID" >
    <img src="http://images.mydomain.com/productimages/@ViewData["ManufacturerID"]/category-@(p.CategoryID)_lg.jpg?width=200&height=130" width="200" height="130" class="myImg" alt="" />      
 </a>  
}
```

We are using explicit expression inside the image source string (  `@(p.CategoryID)`  )

Comment: That does not work because .net looks for a property @p.CategoryID_lg

Comment: @Slee: Fixed. Used Explicit expression.

Comment: ahhh!  nice - this was killing me!

Answer (score 1):

In your link href just use `@p.CategoryID`. The `Html.Display()` is used to show value from model's property. Your model doesn;t contains CategoryID property because it's a collection.

Comment: That does not work because .net looks for a property @p.CategoryID_lg, see answer below by Shyju - that is what I tried first